# How to use Javascript to get information from within a virtual DOM - "#document"?

Tags: javascript, dom, virtual

In my Javascript query I am using the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("x-border-panel x-border-layout-ct")[1].getElementsByClassName("x-border-panel")[0];
```

This then gives me the following result:

```
<iframe id="ext-comp-1053" name="ext-comp-1053" class=" x-border-panel">
   #document
     <html class="ext-strict">
       <body class="caseTab detailPage">
         <div class="linkList">...</div>
           <a class="link">
             <span class="listTitle">"Example"</span>
```

What command do I need to use so I can get the information from the "listTitle" class?

Comment: Is that a virtual DOM or just an iframe's document? Because it looks like an iframe, and that's answered here: [Get IFrame's document, from JavaScript in main document](//stackoverflow.com/q/3999101)

Comment: `contentWindow.document`

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementByClassName('listTitle')
```

[Here is the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: That will not match an element in an iframe's document, nor in a virtual DOM's. The OP is already using that function in the code posted, so I'm sure the link to the documentation is not needed.